# How to call Apache NMS from in a sandbox?

Tags: apache, dynamics-crm-2011, activemq-classic, sandbox, apache-nms

I'm trying to call Apache ActiveMQ NMS Version 1.6.0 from my code ('IntPub') that must run in a sandbox in a .NET 4.0 environment for security reasons.  The program that creates the sandbox makes my code 'partially trusted' and therefore 'security-transparent' which seems to mean that it can't create a ConnectionFactory (see error log below) because NMS seems to be 'security-critical'.  Here's the code that's causing this error:

```
connecturi = new Uri("tcp://my.server.com:61616"); 
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(connecturi);
```

I also tried this instead with similar results:

```
connecturi = new Uri("activemq:tcp://my.server.com:61616"); 
var connectionFactory = NMSConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionFactory(connecturi);
```

Since I can't change the security level of my assembly (the sandbox prevents it) is there a way to make NMS run as 'safe-critical' so it can be called by 'security-transparent' code?  Would I have to recompile it to do so, or does NMS do some operation that would never be considered 'safe-critical?

I appreciate any help or suggestions...

---

```
Assembly 'IntPub, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6fa620743b8dc60a' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Test.Client: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Test.Client.Execute(System.IServiceProvider)' to access security critical method 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory..ctor(System.Uri)' failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message attributes, it looks like you're running a Dynamics CRM 2011 plugin in sandbox mode, which has some very specific rules about what you can and can't do. In particular, you're only allowed to make network connections via HTTP and HTTPS, so attempting raw TCP sockets will definitely fail.

Take a look at this MSDN page on [Plug-in Isolation, Trusts, and Statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx).  It looks like there may be a way to relax the network restrictions by modifying a system registry entry to include tcp, etc, in the regex value.  Below is an excerpt from the page.  **Note:** I have not done this myself, so can't say for sure it'll work.

> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
>   support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
>   feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
>   apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
> - Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
> - IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
> - Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.
>
> These default web access restrictions are defined in a registry key on
>   the server that is running the Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService.exe
>   process. The value of the registry key can be changed by the System
>   Administrator according to business and security needs. The registry
>   key path on the server is:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM\SandboxWorkerOutboundUriPattern**
>
> The key value is a regular expression string that defines the web access restrictions. 
>   The default key value is:
>
> *"^http[s]?://(?!((localhost[:/])|([.*])|([0-9]+[:/])|(0x[0-9a-f]+[:/])|(((([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9A-F]+)).){3}(([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9A-F]+))[:/]))).+";*
>
> By changing this registry key value, you can change the web access for sandboxed plug-ins.

Comment: Thanks, John.  You're right about that restriction, but unfortunately it can't be changed for CRM Online.  So it begs the question, "Is there a way to get NMS to communicate with ActiveMQ via http:?"  Also, begs the question, "Is there anything else that NMS does that would violate the security model?"

Comment: If you're targeting CRM Online, you may have better luck hosting a webservice in Azure (or elsewhere) that does the work you need and calling that webservice from your plugin. Comes with a latency cost, though, so be careful -- especially since plugins have a max amount of time they can run before CRM kills them off.